# React not making a request from docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, axios

so I'm developing a basic Express backend for a React app.
The request is being made like this:

```
axios.get(`${serverLocation}/api/graph/32`).then(res => {
            this.setState({datag: res.data});
            for(var key in this.state) {
                data.push(this.state[key]);
            }
        });
```

Server locations looks like http://IP:PORT.
The api is correct and everything I can see and on my development machine it works. React makes successful requests to the server at specified location etc. The thing is, when I put this into 2 separate docker containers via docker-compose.yml it won't work.
This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  server:
    restart: always
    container_name: varno_domov_server
    build: .
    ports:
    - "8088:5000"
    links:
    - react
    networks:
      - varnodomovnetwork
  react:
    restart: always
    container_name: varno_domov_client
    build: client/
    ports:
    - "8080:3000"
    networks:
      - varnodomovnetwork
networks:
  varnodomovnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

I also have custom Dockerfiles, the server looking like:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And the client looking like:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

If you've made it this far reading, thank you for taking the time. I am open to any suggestions regarding docker here, the React part is not written by me. If any additional information is required, tell me in the comments. Isolation is making me very available :)

Comment: What's the value of `serverLocation`?

Comment: try `server:8088`

Comment: With or without the http? StackOverflow comments are deleting that part for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210121/discussion-between-stefan-golubovic-and-mercenex).

Comment: I've figured out the problem. I'll answer this thread as soon as possible. I've deleted 2 of my comments to not have my IP and domain publicly available to everyone :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the thing was that React was submitting requests to the server. I am inexperienced with React, so I was looking for logs in the terminal/bash when they were actually available in the browser to look at.

The problem was, that my server was on a public IP and communicating via HTTP. This meant the browser blocked the content (Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint), making my graphs display no data. An easy fix is to just make the browser go through with unsafe content, although I am not about that life. So I did the following:
The key problem was that my server and client are 2 separate containers. Therefore, on separate ports. What I've done is edit my nginx configuration to proxy any requests to my domain looking like "https://www.example.come/api" to be forwarded to the port of the server container on the server machine.

Hope this is of any help to someone :)